# What is the policy gradient when multiple actions are possible?

Tags: neural-network, reinforcement-learning

I am trying to program a reinforcement learning algorithm using policy gradients, as inspired by [Karpathy's blog article](http://karpathy.github.io/2016/05/31/rl/). Karpathy's example has only two actions UP or DOWN, so a single output neuron is sufficient (high activation=UP, low activation=DOWN). I want to extend this to multiple actions, so I believe I need a softmax activation function on the output layer. However, I am not certain about what the gradient for the output layer should be.

If I was using a cross-entropy loss function with the softmax activation in a supervised learning context, the gradient for neuron is simply:

```
g[i] = a[i] - target[i]
```

where `target[i] = 1` for the desired action and `0` for all others.

To use this for reinforcement learning I would multiply `g[i]` by the discounted reward before back-propagating.

However, it seems that reinforcement learning uses negative log-likelihood as the loss instead of cross-entropy. **How does that change the gradient?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: something that I think will get you on the right track:

The negative log likelihood is also know as the multiclass cross-entropy (Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning).

EDIT: misread the question. I thought this was talking about Deep Deterministic Policy Gradients

It would depend on your domain, but with a softmax, you are getting a probability across all output nodes. To me that doesn't really make sense in most domains when you think about DDPG. For example, if you are controlling the extension of robotic arms and legs, it wouldn't make sense to have limb extension measured as [.25, .25, .25, .25], if you wanted to have all limbs extended. In this case, .25 could mean fully extended, but what happens if the vector of outputs is [.75,.25,0,0]? So in this way, you could have a separate sigmoid function from 0 to 1 for all action nodes, where then you could represent it as [1,1,1,1] for all arms being extended. I hope that makes sense.

Since the actor network is what determines the actions in DDPG, we could then represent our network like this for our robot (rough keras example):

```
state = Input(shape=[your_state_shape])
hidden_layer = Dense(30, activation='relu')(state)
all_limbs = Dense(4, activation='sigmoid')(hidden_layer)
model = Model(input=state, output=all_limbs)
```

Then, your critic network will have to account for the action dimensions.

```
state = Input(shape=[your_state_shape])
action = Input(shape=[4])
state_hidden = Dense(30, activation='relu')(state)
state_hidden_2 = Dense(30, activation='linear')(state_hidden)
action_hidden = Dense(30, activation='linear')(action)
combined = merge([state_hidden_2, action_hidden], mode='sum')
squasher = Dense(30, activation='relu')(combined)
output = Dense(4, activation='linear')(squasher) #number of actions
```

Then you can use your target functions from there. Note, I don't know if this working code, as I haven't tested it, but hopefully you get the idea.

Source: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1509.02971.pdf
Awesome blog on this with Torc (not created by me): https://yanpanlau.github.io/2016/10/11/Torcs-Keras.html

In the above blog, they also show how to use different output functions, such as one TAHN, and two sigmoid functions for actions.

Comment: many thanks for your help.  I completely understand what you are saying about not using softmax if your output is controlling a set of continuous parameters (joint angles or torques for example).  Your links to the continuous control work are really interesting and I hope to try these techniques in the future.

Comment: Right now I am just starting to learn about RL. My application is Yet-another-rat-in-a-labyrinth.  States are just the grid contents in the cells around the rat.  My action space is small and discrete, consisting of movements in 8 compass directions.  I select a direction stochastically from the probabilities returned by softmax and then do positive or negative reinforcement depending on whether the move extended the distance travelled (measured over last 5 steps), or whether it crashes into a wall. I had a doubt over the form of the loss function (cross-entropy or -ve log-likelihood).

Comment: Reading up on entropy and cross-entropy it now appears to me that cross-entropy loss is identical to log-likelihood loss when the output is 1-hot (i.e. the training examples always specify a SINGLE correct output neuron). I still have a doubt over whether it is admissible to back propagate a negative number for negative reinforcement, but I think that should go in a separate question.

Comment: Updated answer on top with what might answer your question? I am a little confused re-reading it, if this is where you are getting at.

Comment: Yes.  I understood the derivation of the output layer gradient when using cross-entropy with softmax, but I did not know what the gradient should be when using negative log likelihood (as Karpathy does in his blog). I realized in the end that it was just terminology that was confusing me.  It is essentially the same thing.